# Search in favorites as well as questions

Tags: support, meta

I tried the meta posts, but I could not find the answer. How do search a certain keyword that is either in my answers or in my favorites?

I tried the below and it didn't work.

```
user:me is:answer or infavorites:me window
```

The following gives results

```
user:me is:answer window
```

and

```
infavorites:me window
```

but how do I combine them in a single search and get both the results together?

Comment: Its `infavorites:mine` for searching in your favorites

Comment: both infavorites:mine  infavorites:me translates to logged in user.. so that is not a issue

Comment: oh.. they don't seem to have mentioned it in the search tips. In the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), "or" is specified only for tags.

Comment: The strong, strong likelihood is that this search type simply isn't supported for anything that isn't a tag.